# loading data in gridview is slow

Tags: asp.net, linq

For having the result like below and showing column 2 (user control) & column 3 (user control) grouped by column 1. I have made the code like below but it is slow , actually when I use just column 1 , loading is quick (5 seconds) , when I use column 1 & column2 (user control "document list") loading is 10 seconds, and when I use column 1 & column 2 (document list") & column3 ("DocTransList") loading is 45 seconds. I think my code in LINQ is not efficient , but I do not know how to solve it.

```
TRANSMITTAL No        Documents           REV
TT-001                DOC-001              01
                      DOC-002              01
```

```
public partial class Transmittals : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  class TransmittalPresentationModel
  {
    public int TransID { get; set; }
    public String TransmittalNo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblDocument> Documents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblTransmittall> DocTrans { get; set; }
  }

  private EDMSDataContext _DataContext;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      DisplayAuthors();
    }
  }

  private void DisplayAuthors()
  {
    var query =
      from transmittal in _DataContext.tbltransmittalNos
      orderby transmittal.TRANSMITTAL
      select new TransmittalPresentationModel
      {
        TransID = transmittal.TransID,
        TransmittalNo = transmittal.TRANSMITTAL,
        Documents = transmittal.tblTransmittalls.Select(Transmittals => Transmittals.tblDocument),
        DocTrans = transmittal.tblTransmittalls

      };
    GridViewTransmittals.DataSource = query.ToList();
    GridViewTransmittals.DataBind();
  }

  protected void GridViewTransmittals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.DataItem == null) return;

    TransmittalPresentationModel transmittal = (TransmittalPresentationModel)e.Row.DataItem;

    DocumentList documentList = (DocumentList)e.Row.FindControl("DocumentList1");
    DocTransList doctranslist = (DocTransList)e.Row.FindControl("DocTransList2");

    documentList.Documents = transmittal.Documents;
    documentList.DataBind();

    doctranslist.DocTrans = transmittal.DocTrans;
    doctranslist.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `Document` contain a binary object? And why is everything nested in one class?

Comment: no document is string. about "nested in one class" because i do not know more what i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your having issues because your records all need to load into the GridView on each page load / refresh. This pulls from the database and draws each row each time which is time consuming.

Better options are to use Ajax to load your GridView.

Or use Paging on the server side and only give the data to your page it needs.